# JSF p:commandLink and p:ajax have different behavior in update

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a menu with list items and a `p:commandLink` inside. While using this for different pages I realized that I have problems updating form with a `p:dataTable` and `p:columns` inside. After clicking on the link, `form2` which actually has some panels and the table inside should be updated. Now my problem: Only *most* of the content in  `form2` is updated correctly, but the `p:columns` have the *old* value. If I click again on the link, the correct values are shown.

The bean method `public void selectProject(Project myProject)` is called correctly and the values are correctly processed.

Now the strange thing: If I add a `h:graphicImage` with a `p:ajax` everything works fine!!

```
<h:form id="form1">
  ...
  <li>
    <p:commandLink update=":form2" actionListener="#{bean.selectProject(p)}">  
      <h:outputText value="#{p.name}" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <!-- Code below is for testing only, but works fine! -->
    <h:graphicImage value="#{iconBean.icon(12,'clock')}">
      <p:ajax event="click" update=":form2" listener="#{bean.selectProject(p)}"/>
    </h:graphicImage>
  </li>
  ...
</h:form>
```

**Update** This does not seem to be related to `p:columns`, a simplified test case shows the expected behavior of `p:commandLink`. In the original (still failing) setting the menu is implemented as a composite component.

Comment: Are your forms nested? Don't nest forms in web development, it'll result in all kinds of DOM issues like the one you're experiencing

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I use

```
<h:commandLink>
  <h:outputText value="#{p.name}"/>
  <p:ajax event="click" update=":form2" listener="#{bean.selectProject(p)}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```